# Do I need to share a (consented) recording of a conversation

Tags: united-kingdom, recording

I recorded a meeting, which all parties (2 people from one company and myself) were aware of and agreed to.

The conversation that was recorded contains some controversial remarks made by the other party.

Am I legally obliged to share the recording? What if the other party requests a copy of it?

I fully intend on sharing but was hoping to some legal advice on the remarks beforehand.

There are other issues ongoing, and particularly as I was outnumbered, I made the recording to protect my own interests - I am trying to seek some free legal counsel for the overarching situation...

...after a very positive initial meeting, the law centre I first engaged came back after around a week and advised they could not take the case due to complexity and time associated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No offense, but could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the other parties made receiving a copy a condition of their consent to being recorded you have no obligation to give it to them.

If the matter were ever litigated or arbitrated they could subpoena it and you would be obliged to provide it. If the don’t subpoena it and you intend to use it as evidence, you must provide it to them as you must with all evidence.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your recording you should be able to do what you want with it.

Not knowing what is on the recording makes it difficult to know exactly why you would be leery, but if the tape really is your property you can do with it as you please.